# Are there any frameworks or libraries for logging errors remotely with .Net?

Tags: .net, logging, exception

I'd like all of my .Net applications to be able to log unhandled exceptions via the internet when a connection is available. Are there any libraries people use for this purpose (preferably free/open source)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log4Net will do that, specifically through the use of Appenders like the [SmtpAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.html).

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html

Comment: Someone has written a log4net Web Service appender on CodeProject- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Log4NetWebServiceAppender.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Loads.  [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) may have something, and if not, you could easily write a log4net plugin that called a WCF or asmx web service that would record the log somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ELMAH can do whatever you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Comment: Can ELMAH be used with .Net client apps too? Their page only discusses ASP.Net.

Comment: I'm not an expert on ELMAH (defer's to someone who is), but I believe that it's only ASP.NET (or MVC, etc...)